# Decomposing prices into different independent components

Tags: decomposition

Are there any known algorithms that can split up the prices into it's components?
I have a pseudo-competitor dataset that looks like the following:

| Prices | Fuel Type | Brand | Doors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15,000 | Gas | Audi | 4 |
| 23,150 | Diesel | BMW | 2 |
| 32,100 | Gas | Royce | 2 |

For instance, through the algorithm (if available), the component Audi should be worth 7,000, 4 doors could be worth 3,000, and gas as fuel type should be worth 5,000 and running it to a total of $15,000.

This enables me to figure out the cost for each component, and thereby with any permutation, it should be able to generate the price. The rationale is that this will be used in a conjoint study at a later stage once I can figure out each component.

Many thanks in advance if someone can kindly point me in the right direction. The prices do not need to sum to the same, but it should be ideally in the ballpark figure.

Comment: Could you describe your data more? How many observations (rows) and how many predictors (columns)? Have you heard of regression?

Comment: Seems that a regression `price ~ doors+fuel+...` is the solution to your question.

Comment: In terms of observation, it can be between 20 and 100 observations, and there may be other columns (i.e. region / features) etc, and the idea is to find out how much "price" each feature would account for. 

Indeed, I was thinking of using multiple linear regressions, but it's more of a "prediction" instead of "allocation" of prices. I was wondering if there are other methods to do so that I'm aware of (given that I have limited stats background).

Comment: Regression is not useful only for prediction. Think for instance when you want to estimate a curve or a surface. With regression, you could estimate, for instance, the average price for a 4-door car conditionally on a model or marginally for every possible model, etc. Is this what you are asking for?